# AJAX JSON Views

Tags: 7, views, ajax

In Drupal 7 how can I get Views data encoded as JSON? There's the built-in `http://yourdrupal/views/ajax` URL that will return the View data as HTML. For instance it will return:

```
   {
      "command":"insert",
      "method":"replaceWith",
      "selector":".view-dom-id-1",
      "data":"...a bunch of HTML here...",
      "settings":null
   }
```

The `data` is correct but it's formatted as HTML - how can it be formatted as JSON instead?

Answer (score 9):

Check out [views_datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource). It allows to specify a views display of type 'JSON'.